# How do I represent this object unambiguously?

Tags: python

I have written a class `MyPoint`:

```
import math

class MyPoint:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x,self.y = x,y

    def __str__(self,x=0,y=0):
        return "{}".format((self.x,self.y))

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

    def move_to(self, new_x, new_y):
        self.x = new_x
        self.y = new_y

    def get_distance(self, other_point):
        distance = math.sqrt(((other_point.x - self.x)**2)+((other_point.y - self.y)**2))
        return distance

    def is_near_by(self, other_point):
        distance = MyPoint.get_distance(self, other_point)
        if distance < 5.0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Now I need to write the `MyLine` class.

Define a class named `MyLine` by using the `MyPoint` class. A line is composed of two points. The `MyLine` class contains the following:

- A data field named start_point of type `MyPoint` that defines the start point.
- A data field named end_point of type `MyPoint` that defines the end point.
- A constructor/initializer which takes 4 integers as parameters `(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y)` and creates a line with two `MyPoint` objects or creates a line with the default values. The default value for each coordinate is `0`.

This is the code I have written to use the `__repr__(self)` method to represent it as follows:

```
c1 = MyLine(10, 20, 20, 30)
print(repr(c1))
```

produces

```
MyLine(10, 20, 20, 30)
```

My code:

```
class MyLine:
    def __init__(self,start_x=0, start_y=0, end_x=0, end_y=0):
        self.start_x, self.start_y, self.end_x, self.end_y = start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y

        start_point = MyPoint(start_x, start_y)
        self.start_point = start_point

        end_point = MyPoint(end_x, end_y)
        self.end_point = end_point

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} to {}".format(self.start_point, self.end_point)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyLine({}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.start_x, self.start_y, self.end_x, self.end_y)
```

My issue is in the `__repr(self)__`.

Test1:

```
line1 = MyLine(10, 20, 20, 30)
print(repr(line1))
line2 = MyLine()
print(repr(line2))
print(type(line1.start_point))
```

Expected Output1:

```
MyLine(10, 20, 20, 30)
MyLine(0, 0, 0, 0)
<class '__main__.MyPoint'>
```

Received Output1:

```
MyLine(10, 20, 20, 30)
MyLine(0, 0, 0, 0)
<class '__main__.MyPoint'>
```

Test2:

```
line1 = MyLine()
line1.start_point = MyPoint(100, 200)
line1.end_point = MyPoint(-100, 40)
print(repr(line1))
```

Expected Output2:

```
MyLine(100, 200, -100, 40)
```

Received Output2:

```
MyLine(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Where am I going wrong? I know there is an issue with what I'm doing in the `.format()` part but not sure what's the issue.

Comment: You never actually change the values of `line1.start_x`, `line1.start_y`, `line1.end_x`, or `line1.end_y`, only the values of `line1.start_point` and `line1.end_point`. So your `__repr__` function prints out their original values, defined in the constructor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: When you initialize `line1` the values of those variables are all set to zero. Setting `line1.start_point = MyPoint(100, 200)` and `line1.end_point = MyPoint(-100, 40)` doesn't change that.

Comment: As good coding practice, you shouldn't have those redundant variables anyway. Whenever you need `start_x`, instead reference `start_point.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways.
First is to change

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "MyLine({}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.start_point.x, self.start_point.y, self.end_point.x, self.end_point.y)
```

2nd, is to use attribute getters and setters.

```
class MyLine:
    def __init__(self,start_x=0, start_y=0, end_x=0, end_y=0):
        self.start_x, self.start_y, self.end_x, self.end_y = start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y

        start_point = MyPoint(start_x, start_y)
        self._start_point = start_point

        end_point = MyPoint(end_x, end_y)
        self._end_point = end_point

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} to {}".format(self._start_point, self._end_point)

    @property
    def start_point(self):
        return self._start_point

    @start_point.setter
    def start_point(self, point):
        self._start_point = point
        self.start_x = point.x
        self.start_y = point.y

    @property
    def end_point(self):
        return self._end_point

    @end_point.setter
    def end_point(self, point):
        self._end_point = point
        self.end_x = point.x
        self.end_y = point.y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyLine({}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.start_x, self.start_y, self.end_x, self.end_y)
```